# remove all links from within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I've embedded a custom ggl map within a container div using javascript (not the google iframe), and a div to display the map within the first/original container div. I need to deactivate all links within either div so that the links in the embedded map are not clickable.

I've tried the following JQuery solution but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
 $("#map_canvas a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```

Then I've tried the following CSS solution but it blocks the user's ability to pan the map.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

How can I enable user interactivity with the map while preventing anchor links from working within the embedded map? Thanks!

Comment: Strange that your current js-code doesn't work. You sure it is the correct selector?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your first problem is that those links are created dynamically.  So, when you call `$("#map_canvas a")`, there are no `a` elements to bind to.  You might try the delegated syntax of `bind()`.  Assuming `#map_canvas` exists when your script is called (and I would recommend putting your code in a `ready` block):

```
$( function() { 

    $('#map_canvas').on('click', 'a', function() {
        // return false will preventDefault and stopPropagation in jQuery
        return false;  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following code, if there are elements nested inside the  tag. Otherwise they will be removed aswell.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map_canvas a").removeAttr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this.

```
$('#map_canvas a').click(function () {return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the `<a>` elements themselves. I don't know if that's what you want:

```
$("#map_canvas a").remove();
```

But as has already been said, you have to wait for the DOM to be ready because those links are probably automatically generated and are not part of the initial, static layout, and therefore are not bind to the DOM.

So, this could do the trick (it will be executed only when the DOM is ready) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map_canvas a").remove();
});
```

If you dont want to remove the `<a>` elements in themselves and just deactivate them, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map_canvas a").on('click', 'a', function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```